# Relation between squarefree algorithms and radical of ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

For univariate polynomials, I can compute the squarefree variant with the same roots as $p / \text{gcd}(p, dp/dx)$, which is simple enough.

Then I learned about radical of ideals generated by multivariate polynomials, and it seems that it is [non-trivial to get the generator set of the radical ideal](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81979797.pdf), at least for the general case.

But it seems to me that if I could compute the squarefree version of each multivariate polynomial in the generating set, I would get the same variety, and since there is no $f$ such as $f^{m>1} = g$ if $g$ is squarefree, then this ideal must be radical.

Is my reasoning correct? If I can compute the squarefree variants of my polynomials with an algorithm such as [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81979797.pdf), then they generate the radical ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can't work in general. Try $(x,y^2+x)$: both are irreducible and therefore square-free, but $(x,y^2+x)=(x,y^2)$ which is not radical. Your impression that finding generator sets for radical ideals is somewhat difficult is correct.